# Where to give the dependency of the generated java class in bpmn?

Tags: eclipse, maven, wso2, wso2-business-process

The bpmn(using eclipse for WSO2) I have created, is using a java class in service task. The java class that is to be used with the business process is ready as a jar file. Do I have to give this jar file as a dependency somewhere?
And if so, then where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a jar you can put it in the repository/components/lib directory and restart the server. Then at the server startup it will be converted to a bundle and get install to the server

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. But now I'm getting another error message :  "error Starting process : java.lang.Long cannot be cast into java.lang.String".

Comment: That much be due to a error in your code. Check on that line